# How to fix heroku app deployment? App runs locally but not online

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a dog breed classifier django app on heroku, but for some reason heroku doesn't seem to find the path to the exported pkl model file. Whenever I run locally, everything works fine. I'm using the "path" module's "exist()" method to check for the presence of the file first before importing the module, hence the reason for the exception thrown. [Image of app file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o5iM.jpg)

Here's the stack trace for the error:

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://mydogbreed.herokuapp.com/

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.9.6

```
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'api.apps.ApiConfig',
 'corsheaders',
 'frontend']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 167, in _get_response
    callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs = self.resolve_request(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 290, in resolve_request
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 556, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/breed_classifier/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from api import views
  File "/app/api/views.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise Exception("Model path doesn't exist")

Exception Type: Exception at /
Exception Value: Model path doesn't exist
```

Comment: Can you add directory structure?

Comment: [Here is the file structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o5iM.jpg)

Comment: Did you include all apps in main app url’s?